# Force language code in django

Tags: python, django, locale

I have a website with two languages. Turkish and English. 
I already setup django internalization with gettext.
If browser request Turkish it translates to Turkish.
If browser request English it translates to English.
But i only want Turkish language to show users.
How can i set language to Turkish permanently?(I am using django 1.3)
Thanks.

Comment: You want only Turkish no English, is this correct? Can you remove the English setting from the LANGUAGE tuple?

Answer (score 3):

> If all you want to do is run Django with your native language, and a language file is available for it, all you need to do is set LANGUAGE_CODE.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#language-code